# Pass object into component as a prop and render each item in the object

Tags: reactjs

**GOAL**: Pass object as a prop to a component and then render each item in the object in a `p` tag

Here is the code where I pass the object into my `ProductDetails` component as the `bullets` prop:

```js
return (
    <div className="product">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <ProductDetails
              bullets={product.productBullets}
            />
          ))}
    </div>
```

This is what my `productBullets` object looks like:

`productBullets: {secondBullet: " asdf", thirdBullet: "ads", firstBullet: " asdf", fourthBullet: "adf "}`

I pass `bullets` as a prop from my `ProductPage` component to my `ProductDetails` component here:

```js
function ProductDetails({ bullets }) {
  return (
    <div className="product__details">
        {bullets.map((bullet) => (
          <p>{bullet}</p>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, when I try to map through the object, the items don't render. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` function does not work because it's not an *array*, it's an *object*.

```
{Object.values(bullets || {}).map((bullet, i) => (
   <p key={i}>{bullet}</p>
))}
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: @d-dripz Does the data come from async request? Updated answer.

Comment: I'm fetching the data from firebase with a useEffect hook and then passing the bullet point data as a prop to the component. Also, the error doesn't show anymore with the new code but the bullet points aren't rendering on the screen.

Comment: @d-dripz Then theres a problem with your data fetching probably. The code Ive posted above should display data properly, if only data exists.

Comment: Caught the bug. Works like a charm now. Thank you!